# #1215 SQL Cannot add foreign key constraint error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my code. I can't figure out why I can't add the constraint.

```
Create table customer(
    UserId Integer
)

CREATE TABLE Date(
    DateID      INTEGER,
    User1ID     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    User2ID     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Date        CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    GeoLocation CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    BookingFee  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CustomerRepresentative  CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Comments    CHAR(200),
    User1Ratings    CHAR(20),
    User2Ratings    CHAR(20),
    Primary Key (DateID),
    Check ( User1Ratings IN (‘Excellent’, ‘VeryGood’, ‘Good’, ‘Fair’, ‘Poor’) ),
    Check ( User2Ratings IN (‘Excellent’, ‘VeryGood’, ‘Good’, ‘Fair’, ‘Poor’) ),
    FOREIGN KEY (User1ID) REFERENCES customer(UserID)
)
```

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of the `CHECK` constraints for `User1Ratings` and `User2Ratings`, consider creating a separate look-up table `Ratings` that contains the five string values as the primary keys; then make `User1Ratings` and `User2Ratings` foreign keys to the `Ratings` table.

Comment: (cont'd:) Advantages: **1.** It's easier to discover the range of valid values for the two columns (no need to look at the definition of the `CHECK` constraint; just look at the contents of the `Ratings` table). **2.** More flexibility: It's easy to add new ratings. Just insert into `Ratings`, no need to redefine several `CHECK` constraints. Using `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, renaming a rating becomes easy: Just `UPDATE` the `Ratings` table, and all references in `Date` are adjusted automatically.

Comment: The **`sql-server`** tag on this question specifies Microsoft SQL Server. But the Error "1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint" is a MySQL error. The Stackoverflow tag for MySQL is **`mysql`**.

Comment: Related to the previous comments from stakx regarding `CHECK` constraints: MySQL accepts the syntax for CHECK constraints but does **not enforce** check constraints. The foreign key constraint (as described by stakx) would be enforced tables using a storage engine that supports foreign keys (e.g. InnoDB, but not MyISAM). Another option provided by MySQL (that works with MyISAM as well as InnoDB) is the ENUM datatype. For example, the `User1Ratings` column  could be defined as datatype `ENUM('Excellent','VeryGood','Good','Fair','Poor')`.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely explanation for the behavior is that `UserID` column is not defined as the PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE KEY in the `customer` table

One fix for this would be to re-write the create for the `customer` table

For SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE customer
( UserId Integer NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT PK_customer PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserId)
);
```

For MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE customer
( UserId INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
);
```

Comment: omg thank you i forgot